# Raster calculator expression

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, expression, formula

I'm looking for raster calculator expression which includes the "STATISTICS_MEAN" value from the raster properties.

How can I build the expression, that the value is automatically adapted?

I want to build a workflow in the Graphical Modeler. One step should be to calculate the relativ percent of all values in the raster. For this I need to know the Statistics_mean value in advance. Calculating everything step by step is no problem, but I would like to use a workflow in the model builder. The formula I need is like this: "'raster'@1" / STATISTICS_MEANraster@1 *100

Comment: Are you asking how to access the mean-value obtained through the `raster layer statistics` tool and hand it to the raster calculator?

Comment: @Erik: Yes, exactly. I would like to use the mean value and include it automatically in the raster calculator in the Graphical Modeler. Unfortunately I don't have a clever solution.